# Lambda function returns the JSON object as string to the AppSync

Tags: python, aws-appsync

I have a chalice application and in that chalice application, I have a lambda function. This lambda function is the data source for my AppSync application. When I make a request and return the response from the Lmabda function, the JSON object is returned as string, and not as JSON object. I have tried so many times, but nothing worked.

This is what I am returning from the lambda function:

```
'''
 result = {
                    'service': service,
                    'version': version,
                    'requestID': request_id,
                    'result': {
                        'creditDecisionRecommendation': credit_decision_recommendation,
                        'creditScore': bureau_score,
                        'creditLimit': limit
                    }
                }
'''
```

...and this is what I get as the response:

```
'''
{
  "data": {
    "postKaubamaja": {
      "service": "kaubamaja-custom-scoring",
      "version": "1.0",
      "result": "{\"creditDecisionRecommendation\":\"accept\",\"creditScore\":10.8,\"creditLimit\":612.1275}"
    }
  }
}
'''
```

The "result" object should be a JSON object itself, but gets a string. 
Does someone have any idea what is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I've waisted one day on this, it shouldn't be so complicated. I tried changing the result type from String to AWSJSON, lambda resolver returning a object or a json string and even play with the response template.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, to turn the dictionary into JSON string just use `json.dumps`. Given the following input:

```
 result = {
                    'service': 'A',
                    'version': 'B',
                    'requestID': 'C',
                    'result': {
                        'creditDecisionRecommendation': 'D',
                        'creditScore': 123,
                        'creditLimit': 4
                    }
                }
```

you just need this line:

```
import json
json.dumps(result)
```

and gives the JSON string representation of the dictionary `result` (which is a JSON object):

```
'{"service": "A", "version": "B", "requestID": "C", "result": {"creditDecisionRecommendation": "D", "creditScore": 123, "creditLimit": 4}}'
```

**Note**: In python, each dictionary is by nature a JSON object.

Comment: Add the complete code of your function, with input and expected output

Comment: @uuzzairr agreed, please post your source if you would like a resolution.

Comment: @Massifox I know how to convert a string into JSON and vice versa. I have tried different options. I am using AppSynch with lambda function as a data source and using GraphQL to query the result from the API. What's happening is that it turns one of the dictionary objects into string even though I return it as a dictionary. I tried several approaches, but nothing is working. Maybe it is something to do with GraphQL?